# How to get a 'last stable' version of the V8 sources

Tags: git, v8

I installed "git for windows" version 2.10.0 and "depot_tools", then successfully ran the `fetch v8` command.

For reference, I had to fix one problem: `fetch` breaks if there is no `DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0` environment variable.

Anyway, I know have a v8 source tree, with 55k files (1Go), and the next step is to build V8 (for Windows)

My question: `git branch` says:

```
* (HEAD detached at origin/master)
  master
```

I see [here](http://omahaproxy.appspot.com/) that the last stable version for V8 on win64 is "5.3.332.45".
How do I setup my source tree to be the one used to build that version?

(yes I am a complete newbie to git)(but used with svn)

Comment: what version do you have?   include/v8_version.h I believe

Comment: @xaxxon Version is 5.5.0.0, but I can't see why it matters. Did you understand my question?

Comment: maybe something here? https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code/working-with-release-branches

Comment: @xaxxon Thanks. Good info in your link. What is `your_release_branch`? Also, should I add some prior command, dealing with the `detached HEAD` situation?

Comment: @xaxxon Many thanks. I just choose a name for my branch and did `git checkout -b v8_5_3_332_45 tags/5.3.332.45`. The last outputs was `Branch v8_5_3_332_45 set up to track remote ref refs/tags/5.3.332.45
Switched to a new branch 'v8_5_3_332_45'` and now `v8-version.h` is at 5.3.332.45`. Feel free to elaborate an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the information here: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code/working-with-release-branches

after making sure to have all the tags available:

```
git fetch --tags
```

You can create a branch and check out a tagged release with:

```
git checkout -b BRANCH_NAME tags/TAG_NAME
```

BRANCH_NAME doesn't need to exist, it will be created automatically

TAG_NAME is the value from the tag of the release, which is the `v8_version` field found here: http://omahaproxy.appspot.com/